# Java resources is missing when I update maven project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a project with structure and project facet below:

[image]

But when I update the project, the java resources is missing and when I check to project facet, java, dynamic web module are uchecked but I can't check that module. So, what the process actually when I updated project? How to solve my problem: when I update project, the resources folder is missing?

my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.prudential.integration.middleware</groupId>
    <artifactId>crm-services-sb</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>CRM SERVICES SB</name>
    <url>http://www.myorganization.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <spring.boot-version>1.2.7.RELEASE</spring.boot-version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>Brixton.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>  <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- REST -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quartz2</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- UTILITY -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient-osgi</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore-osgi</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.prudential.enc</groupId>
            <artifactId>pruencutil</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-sql</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.prudential.integration.middleware.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>prudential-fuse-common-model</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-blueprint</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-sql</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-jaxb</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-test-blueprint</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-test</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-core-osgi</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-core-xml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.prudential.integration.middleware.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>prudential-fuse-common-dao</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-blueprint</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.prudential.integration.middleware</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-utilities</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-blueprint</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-sql</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-jaxb</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-test-blueprint</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-test</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-core-osgi</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-core-xml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>org.apache.camel.spring.boot.FatJarRouter</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>repackage</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>sql-jdbc</id>
            <name>SQL JDBC</name>
            <url>http://clojars.org/repo/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Comment: Posting your `pom` would probably help.

Comment: "project facet" and the screenshot seem to imply you're dealing with Eclipse here, so tagging as such. what is your actual error?

Comment: also, you shouldn't be even checking your facets - what should matter is contents of your `pom.xml` file. I wonder if it's been imported properly and, like said, post that instead of your facet screenshot.

Comment: okay. I put my pom.xml

Comment: a Spring Boot should be packaging `jar` or `war` but not `ear`...

Comment: Is your src/main/resources folder missing ?